# Entry only shows "." when in TextedChanged-Event even on different Language Settings

Tags: c#, maui, cultureinfo

I am using VS 2022 and the "Pixel 5 - API 33 (Android 13.0 - API 33)" Emulator and a .NET MAUI App.

In this App, I have an Entry and using my own TextChanged-Event to evaluate if the user entered the right number-Format.

```
private void EntryControl_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var entry = sender as Entry;
    var input = entry.Text;
    var match = Regex.Match(input, "^(0|0[.,][0-9]*|[1-9]+[.,]*[0-9]*)$");

    if (input.Length == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!match.Success)
    {
        entry.Text = e.OldTextValue;
    }

    entry.CursorPosition = e.NewTextValue.Length;
}
```

This should evaluate that only positive values can be entered and also floating point numbers are allowed.

Here, I have the problem that on each Language Setting in my Emulator, I always get a "." for the floating-point separator "12.3". But in German for instance it should be ",".

I even cannot enter a "," in German Language Setting.

Do I have to change anything or is this the default behavior? I want to use and enter "," when Language in the Emulator is set to German and "." when it is set to English. Even better, the Entry should decide what it should be, based on the CultureInfo.